# ios background position

Tags: ios

What is the best way to position background image below header image. Currently I have:

```
header = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h.png"]];
[header setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
[self.window addSubview:header];

background = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
[background setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake(0,header.frameHeight)];
[background addSubview:background];
```

but I get the following error:

```
 No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the sector 'setFrameOrigin.'
```

I want to use UIView method, so that I can place a table view inside background view afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
CGRect rect = background.frame;
rect.oigin.x = x;
rect.origin.y = y;
background.frame = rect;
```

or:

```
background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[background addSubview:background];
```

is not OK in your code. You are trying to add a view as subview to its self.
Just create a rootviewcontroller and set as in your app delegate as rootview controller.

```
self.window.rootViewController = rootviewcontroller;
```

then you can add your background view as subview on the view of rootviewcontroller. after that you can do it for headerview.

```
[rootviewcontroller.view addSubview:background];
[rootviewcontroller.view addSubview: headerview];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[background setFrame:CGRectMake(0, header.frame.size.height, 60, 50)];
```

Try like this it will be helpful to you.

Comment: setFrammeOrigin is still undeclared.

Comment: There is no setFrameOrigin: method. you have to create frame. You can assign values to this frame. This is right way.